# How to transpile typescript for the client

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use our typescript code on the client side but when the JS is generated it starts each file with:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var foo_1 = require("./some file name");
```

When trying to execute in the browser I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

and if I remove the exports it complains about the require.

Given a very simple example, I can reproduce this.

```
// create a file foo.ts and put the following in it.
export class foo{
name:string = "Thomas";
}

// create another file called test.ts and put the following in it.
import { foo } from "./foo";
console.log(new foo().name);

// tsconfig.json
    {
        "compilerOptions": {
            "target": "es5", //defines what sort of code ts generates, es5 because it's what most browsers currently UNDERSTANDS.        
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "removeComments": true,
            "noImplicitAny": false,
            "lib": [
                "es2016",
                "dom",
                "es5"
            ]
        }
    }
```

I'm using Typescript 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

By default, the TypeScript compiler generates CommonJS modules, which browsers can't run directly.  You'll need to use a [module loader or bundler](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+module+(bundler+OR+loader)+for+browser) such as Webpack, Browserify, Rollup, or RequireJS and set TypeScript's `module` compiler option to generate a module format accepted by the loader or bundler you choose.  Or you can use the native module support in recent browsers if you set TypeScript to generate `es6` modules; see, e.g., [this article](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/).