# Include TypeScript into webpage that uses multiple components

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript file that looks a little something like this:

`myTypescript.ts`

```
import { MyFirstClass } from "./MyFirstClass"
import { AnotherClass } from "./AnotherClass"
import { MyThirdClass } from "./MyThirdClass"

var test = new MyFirstClass();
// some more code
```

`MyFirstClass.ts`

```
export class MyFirstClass {
  constructor() {}
}
```

Here is what myTypescript.ts compiles to:

```
1 | "use strict";
2 | exports.__esModule = true;
3 | var MyFirstClass_1 = require("./MyFirstClass");
4 | // more classes included
```

And the HTML that includes the main (compiled) typescript:

`index.html`

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <script src="MyTypescript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But going to `localhost:8080` shows this in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at myTypescript.js:2
```

and commenting out that second line just yields another error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at myTypescript.js:3
```

Perhaps my assumption that TypeScript can simply be compiled into JS is erroneous. I've written half a dozen custom classes, similar to how I would in Java, hoping it would just compile into JS nicely.

Is my code still usable in-browser? *I've tried some of the solutions posted on StackOverflow, but they are a little vague, and don't address the custom classes being includes.* Thanks in advance!

**I'm a little unfamiliar with how the `tsconfig` file works, so I don't actually have one.**

Comment: Please add your `tsconfig.json` to the question, it will make answering much easier.

Comment: @Cerberus edited post.

Comment: Well, then how do you compile these files? Just `tsc <filenames>`, without any additional options?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to transpile typescript for the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261286/how-to-transpile-typescript-for-the-client)

Comment: Yes, just tsc <filename> @Cerberus